# How do I choose the right UML diagram before coding my project?

Tags: uml

I had what I think is a good idea for a mobile application.  The application will consist of the native mobile app, and I will have a backend server that will perform a variety of functions - such as refreshing data sources and parsing the data into a database, responding to user queries, etc.

Before I start coding, I wanted to make sure I could map out everything I need to so I can make sure I have the direction I need.  However, I am unsure if I really should start with a class, activity, or sequence diagram.

I know pretty much how the front end should work, I have some flow charts showing the basics of how the user will interact, but I want to work on the backend and make sure that everything is the way it is supposed to be.  Any help is appreciated!

EDIT
So I think my main question is this: I have an idea for an app, and drew a rudimentary flowchart.  I want to map out all the processes and activities before coding, so I can understand what objects and functions I will need, and how everything should interact.  My flowchart is pretty rudimentary, and there are several concurrent processes (i.e. the User can initiate certain activities, but in the background the server might be polling third party sources for data, etc.).  What is the best process to plan this out?

Comment: If you're doing a small(ish) and relatively simple application by yourself UML is probably going to be of limited value to you.  Most solo-developers scribble something on the back of a napkin and focus on self documenting code.

Answer (score 2):

I will describe the version of [agile modeling](http://www.agilemodeling.com/) that we use in our project. We are building a large application (several thousand lines of code) and a process is absolutely necessary. In a small application, you might find that overkill. On the other hand, following all steps of the process is educational and could prove useful in helping you clarify some aspects of the system. Any modeling technique aims to help you, so you should pick whatever you think is useful and ignore the rest.

1. Start by identifying the use cases. Identify the use cases and give a brief description of each use case. Use case diagrams are not very useful to you. They are useful to somebody else to whom you want to explain what the system is about. What is useful for the system development is the description of the use case. At this stage a brief description (few lines) is enough.
2. Give a detailed description of the flow of events for each use case. You can do that with plain text, but an activity diagram gives a better visualization.
3. Take the activity diagrams one by one and and figure out which class will fulfill each activity. After you do that, you know which classes you need to develop. So you can proceed to the next step.
4. Make class diagrams to visualize the classes and their relationships. Usually here comes the question: How many class diagrams should I draw and how much information should I visualize. It depends: Draw as many diagrams as you think is necessary to present a good visualization of your design.
5. Now you have a design and you can start coding. However it might be useful to draw a sequence diagram or a collaboration diagram for the most important methods.
6. Usually this is enough, but in some types of problems a state diagram might be useful to visualize the state changes of classes or modules.
7. If you want more UML, then you can also draw a deployment diagram to show which parts of the application are deployed on the client and which parts are deployed on the server.

Hope it helps. Don't forget, pick only the steps and diagrams that help you build better code. The diagrams only serve one purpose: To help you (and your team) write the code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever done some software development without UML? Have you done analysis, design?

I am asking this because UML has to do very little with the software methodology as is. It only gives you a set of visual toos to support your methodology, whichever it is. UML proposes a variety of different diagrams, permitting a modeler to depict virtually all aspects of a system under development.

If you already have your prefered software methodology, and especially if it works for you, I would suggest simply to enrich it with a formal modeling notation and specification (UML), keeping the same procedures and steps. Only you know what kind of specifications you make and that give you good results. Use UML in these steps, changing only a **format** of your specs and **not the methodology** itself.

While learning UML diagrams, concentrate on What each diagram puts emphasis on (e.g. deployment on HW-structure, UC on the user-system interaction, sequences on the collaborating objects and the messages exchange, activities on the processes, tasks and data flows, etc).
Depending on what you want to express, chose an adequate UML diagram.

My suggestion is to go slowly and gradually incorporating UML in your methodology and stick to the solid ground. Learn a diagram or two at a time, rather that trying to use everything. If you are unsure whether to diagram something or not - don't do it. If you miss some piece of specification - make a diagram. Concentrate on **what you want to show** (content), instead of **what diagram to use** (form).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Essentially it will mostly be me doing all the work.  I thought the UML would be helpful to visualize everything before I go about doing anything.  My biggest challenge is going to be the architecture - my background is in security, not really knowing how to design a backend (e.g. do I need ElasticSearch/Solr, Redis, what type of db, etc.)

Comment: That's exactly my point - software development is a craft and UML is a tool. If you're not sure how to design a backend, UML cannot do it for you. It can only help you visualising your ideas. About the architecture, I recomment this thread, I think it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517440/software-structure-versus-software-architecture/23518618#23518618

Answer (score 0):

try to draw [Sequence diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) but you need to complete.

> 1- Data Flow diagram is an easy Behavioral diagram to start with.
>
> 2- the Class diagram is a Structural diagram will help you to focus on
>   the structure of your application.

and then you can work on sequence diagram (behavioral) if you finish sequence diagram then you are more than ready to code and I advise you don't go to more detailed diagram before start coding.